# how to create MYSQL User for tableau connectivity only

Tags: mysql, database, devops, operation, tableau-desktop

I want to allow MYSQL connectivity to business users on tableau without creating a DB user i.e. without allowing direct access to the database through the MYSQL workbench.

right now I have a MySQL user with grant access on only one database to connect through tableau. But business users can use this user to explore data through workbench and run queries, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to give MYSQL database access ONLY on tableau and not any database tools like workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for this and here it is, in case someone else has this issue.
I just published a live connection to my database table on tableau server, and embedded user credentials in tableu. This way anytime a user wants to use the data source they just need to select from published data sources. But we wont have to share user credentials with them, that resolves the issue and they wont be able to log in using any credentials from any database client.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such an option for it. But you can create/define user roles with restrictions on DB/table levels in MySQL or you can create two database(on same machine or another machine), one is Main(Primary) and other one for Tableau only, so if any Tableau users access the new(separate) database from any other application, they will have limited data(only which is using for Tableau dashboards).